# `.button()` space behaviour

Tags: jquery-ui

This is my code (http://jsfiddle.net/UXdLQ/3/):

```
$('input').button();
```

One bizarre behaviour is when I hit the space bar, the background color changes to white, which is not consistent with the fact that typing letters does not change the background.

How can I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick & Dirty: (as there isn't an option for this)

```
$('input').bind("keydown", function(event) {
    if ( event.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.SPACE ) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});

$('input').button();
```